# jQuery .scroll to change background like a movie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, preload

I am trying to change the background image of webpage using 200 images and play them like a movie. My code is working, however the transition is flickering when the picture changes on scroll. Seems that during the scroll the CSS is updated and I get a flicker. It is very noticeable in Chrome and Safari, but also does it in FF. Seems smoother in FF. Strange. Need help smoothing things out. I am using the following code below. Please, any help in smoothing out the transition and making it more movie like would be great. I am new to jquery, but have a background in programming. Any and all advice is greatly appreciated!

I have researched for nearly three days. Some have mentioned that updating the .htaccess file helped so that the header of the files are set to not expire and the browser is sending a 304. I dont know how to test, but here is my code below.

```
var pics = []; // CREATE PICS ARRAY

    //PRELOAD FUNCTION TO SET UP PICS ARRAY IN MEMORY USING IMAGE OBJECT
function preload(){
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        pics[i] = new Image();
        pics[i].src = arguments[i]; 
    }
};
preload(
'bgImage/1.jpg'
,'bgImage/2.jpg'
,'bgImage/3.jpg'
,'bgImage/4.jpg'
,'bgImage/5.jpg'
); // THERE ARE 200 TOTAL IMAGES THAT WE ARE LOADING...

function switchImage() {
var s = $(window).scrollTop();
var index = 0;
if(s>   10  ){index =   1   ;}
if(s>   20  ){index =   2   ;}
if(s>   30  ){index =   3   ;}
if(s>   40  ){index =   4   ;}
if(s>   50  ){index =   5   ;}
// THERE IS 200 IF STATEMENTS IN TOTAL
// THE ODER OF THE IMAGES STARTS IN THE MIDDLE AND WE HAVE TO ADJUST DEPENDING ON POSITION
// USING THE IF STATEMENTS WAS THE EASIEST SOLUTION
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(' + pics[index].src + ')');
};

$(document).ready(function () {
switchImage();
//alert("images and dom loaded");
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
switchImage();
});
```

Comment: `THERE IS 200 IF STATEMENTS IN TOTAL` ಠ_ಠ `index = Math.floor(s/10)`

Comment: Eeeek, `$(window).scroll()` fires as often as it can during a scroll action. Read the first paragraph under "Event Performance" **[here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

Comment: What is the s/10 doing to get the index? I am going to try it out this evening.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are named #.jpg wrap preload function into adapter that recieves number of images and iterates preload string like 'bgImage/' + i + '.jpg'.

This way you can immediately get reusable array to use on scroll in combination with switch statement for all 200 segments, which is real pain in the A... or just invoke :

```
index = $(window).scrollTop()/10;
```

This single line should replace all of your indexes, and every time you scroll you will put the right image into background.

As for changing css on javascript/jQuery event, I recommend using jQuery animate with really quick transition of couple ms, but stil a transition.

Comment: any good examples or place to start with the animate. I am going to google search and see what I come up with.